# ion-nav-title with image left justified and text center justified

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

My apologies in advance for what may be a simple css question.  I have an  where in the title, I would like the logo left justified and the view title center justified.  The code looks like the following:

```
 <ion-nav-title>
    <img align="left" src='img/my_logo2.png'>
    <span>Home</span>
</ion-nav-title>
```

I would like the text in the span centered horizontally in the header, but right now it is slightly to the right of center.  I've tried setting text-align and playing with the margins in the style.css file, but I haven't had any luck.  My apologies again, because I'm sure I'm doing something silly.  Thanks!!
JT

Comment: Can you create a demo of it? http://play.ionic.io

Comment: Can you post any relevant CSS?

Comment: I'll see if I can create a demo.  I've tried the following: <ion-nav-title class='myHeader'> where in my style.css file I have .myHeader {text-align: center !important;}

Comment: I now have a codepen example here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/jeffetionic/pen/rVdQKd)

Comment: I now have one working solution where I if I set the position: absolute; left: 15px;  for the image  and text-align: center for the parent div then my text is centered.  I'm wondering if there is another better way to do this.